# Render react component in bundle.js only when a certain page is loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, webpack

I recently started using webpack in my ASP.Net project, and I just wanted to add a new react component as well now.

The following problem just came up for me. I did import my react component in the index file and it gets packed with webpack without any problems.

However, I am loading the bundle.js which webpack outputs in a shared page.

The problem I am facing is the following now:

In the file which contains my react component declaration, let's call it Post.jsx, I am calling `ReactDOM.render(<PostFeed />, document.getElementById('postFeed'));`. Now, as stated, the bundle.js is being loaded on a shared view, so every page initially calls the render function at some point. However, the element 'postFeed' which the component is being rendered inside, is only available when the user navigates to a specific page.

What options do I now have in order to only render my component when I navigated on a certain page? Can I somehow reliably determine this from javascript? I would really like to keep the comfort webpack provides, but I know when there is no other choice I could also split my Post.jsx file and add it as a script in the html code for the specific in which the component does find its element.

Any advice?

Comment: Can't you just do a conditional render of `<Postfeed/>` within your `<App/>` or whatever other component is applicable as parent based on location.href?

Comment: @charlietfl I am not using full react, I just wanted to use it for a certain part of my page. So at the moment, there is no parent. It is embedded in a basic <div>